# Running Eigen's sparse CG solver multi-threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, eigen

I have Matlab code that uses sparse and '\' as solver for a linear system. I have hand tailored a C++ function that uses the conjage gradient sparse solver from Eigen in order to run the code outside Matlab using the coder toolbox to export the rest of the Matlab code. I export a static library and I'm able to compile and execute it on my remote system without any problem. However, I'm not able to run the code using multi-threading. I have tried to export it as a Matlab executable (mex) and the whole code runs in parallel without problem inside Matlab.

So my conclusions are that it must be something different in the compiler/linker flags on my remote system. I use -fopenmp in both complier and linker and I run the executable with OMP_NUM_THREADS=n and if I read out "n" inside my program I get the same number as I have in my execution.

My question is, do I need to include anything else in my compiler/linker, apart from needed things related to my particular code, in order to get Eigen to run multi-threaded?

UPDATE:

On the remote system I do:

```
g++ -c -m64 -fopenmp -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/Eigen/src/misc/
~/src/myHandTailoredFile.cpp -o ~/src/myHandTailoredFile.o
```

and with linker options

```
-fopenmp -L /usr/local/lib64/ -llapack -L /usr/local/lib/ -lcurl
```

To compile my hand tailored file together with myBigProgram into a Mex-file I do

```
g++ -DHAVE_LAPACK_CONFIG_H -DLAPACK_COMPLEX_STRUCTURE -DMW_HAVE_LAPACK_DECLS  -c -ansi -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -D_GNU_SOURCE -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -std=c++0x -fopenmp -DOMPLIBNAME="\"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64/libiomp5.so\"" -O -DNDEBUG -I "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/simulink/include" -I "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/toolbox/shared/simtargets" -I "./interface" -I "/usr/local/lib" -I "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include" -I "." "~/src/myHandTailoredFile.cpp"
```

with linker options set to

```
-pthread -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64 -shared -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++ -lcurl  -fPIC -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/sys/os/glnxa64 -liomp5  -o myBigProgram_mex.mexa64 -L"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64" -lmwblas -lmwlapack   -lemlrt -lcovrt -lut -lmwmathutil
```

Note that the compiler and linker options for the later is completely defined by Matlab.

Comment: Perhaps its smart to post in your question also the compile spec and output (shortest version with relevant info to your question only)...

Comment: Which piece isn't running in parallel? Your code or the generated code? How are you calling MATLAB Coder to generate the standalone code? If the parallelism should be in the generated code, make sure that the setting 
 EnableOpenMP: https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/control-compilation-of-parfor-loops.html?searchHighlight=enableopenmp&s_tid=doc_srchtitle is on

Comment: The part that does not run in parallel is the part where Eigen is used. The parfor-loops of Matlab run in parallel without problem on my remote system. According to Mathworks, the EnableOpenMP is on by default and as I can see, -fopenmp is used when I compile my code on the remote system.